# Subquery returns more than 1 row (Sql Functions)

Tags: mysql, database, function, delimiter, procedure

I have this function that I  want to run ... this function needs to return the job_ids that start with A only... I'm confused!

I'm getting this error!
any ideas... What I know that a function needs to have parameters, but I don't know what to pass...
**23:47:05  select job_id() LIMIT 0, 1000   Error Code: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row**

```
delimiter $
create function Job_id()
returns char
reads sql data
begin
    return (select job_id
            from job_history
            where job_id like 'A%');
end$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Does anybody know how this work?

Comment: In what context do you want to use this? Functions are intended to return scalar values, not table data.  Stored procedures can return table data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) for functions says:

> Statements that return a result set can be used within a stored
>   procedure but not within a stored function

If you need a result set then, as told by @Michael Berkowsky, use stored procedures or maybe a view will do the trick for your needs.